# Duplicate Key Illegal state Exception from Collectors.map

Tags: java, java-8

The code is as below. I am seeing Duplicate key , illegal state Exception.

```
List<User> allusers = Helper.getAllUsers(someKey);
Map<String, User> allusersMap = allusers.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(originalUser-> originalUser.getName(),
originalUser-> originalUser));
```

Comment: `toMap()` takes 3 argument, and the third one is `BinaryOperator `which can help you in ignoring duplicates. `(a,b)->a` would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java docs on `toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) explain this pretty clearly:

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), an IllegalStateException is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator) instead.

So your data have multiple users with the same name, and `toMap` is working as intended. It's always good to rtm :-)

Comment: Resolved using the BinaryOperator                                                                                                    List<User> allusers = Helper.getAllUsers(someKey);
Map<String, User> allusersMap = allusers.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(originalUser-> originalUser.getName(),
originalUser-> originalUser,(userObj1, userObj2) -> userObj1));